# Probability Holiday Light On/Off Question

Tags: probability, self-study, expected-value

In a string of 25 holiday lights, each light is either on or off. The probability of being on is 0.9 for each light, independently of the others. Find the expected value of $Y$= the number of unlike adjacent pairs among the 24 pairs of adjacent lights.

I have tried to define random variables $X_i=1, I=1,2,..,24$ if lights $i$ and $i+1$ are different and otherwise $X_i=0$ and to express $Y$ as a function of the random variables $X_i$.

Comment: I have tried to define random variables Xi=1, I=1,2,..,24 if lights i and i+1 are different and otherwise Xi=0 and to express Y as a function of the random variables Xi.

Comment: Hi, please don't forget to mark the answer if it solved the question for you.

Answer (score 2):

It's usually a good idea to show what you have done so far in order to solve the question, and where are you failing.

But my intuition gives this solution:

The probability of an unlike pair $p(A \neq B)$ is equal to $p(A_{off} \& B_{on}) + p(A_{on} \& B_{off})$,

which is equal to 
$(0.1 \times 0.9) + (0.9 \times 0.1) = 0.18$

Therefore the expected value out of 24 pairs should be 
$= 24 \times0.18 = 4.32$.

Hope it helps !